# Search multiline Textbox for items then check corresponding items in checkedlistbox if found [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net-2010, checkedlistbox

Hello I am having trouble getting this code to work properly. I am trying to load items from a multiline Textbox then search a CheckedListBox for them and check them if they are found.

My CheckedListBox has 4 items. 
Red 
Green 
Black 
Blue

My Textbox has 2 items.
Green
Blue

My issue is when I use the below code, it returns 1 (Green) 0 (Red) and 3 (Blue). It should not return 0 (Red)

Why is it doing that and how can i stop it from returning 0?

I have tried changing TextBox2.Text.Split() to TextBox2.Text.Split(vbNewLine) but that does not work.

Thanks!

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For Each strLine As String In TextBox2.Text.Split()
        Dim i As Integer = CheckedListBox1.FindString(strLine)
        CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndex = i
        CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, True)
        MsgBox(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue myself. I needed to remove the line breaks. I did so with the following code.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For Each strLine As String In TextBox2.Text.Split(vbNewLine)
        Dim i As Integer = CheckedListBox1.FindString(strLine)
        CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndex = i
        CheckedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, True)

    Next
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    TextBox2.Text = Replace(TextBox2.Text, vbLf, "")
End Sub
```

End Class